# Why does modifying a copy of a list also modify other copies of the same list?

Tags: python, list, copy, nested-lists

```
grid = np.empty((10,0)).tolist()
coords = grid.copy()
distances = grid.copy()
print(id(grid), id(coords), id(distances))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        distances[i].append(i+j)
        coords[i].append([i, j])
print(distances)
print(coords)
```

I created a nested list for turning into a 2D grid. I want to create two different 2D grid, one containing the coordinate of each element, the other containing the distance of each coordinate from (0,0).

I used the .copy() method twice, and confirmed that `coords` and `distances` are in fact different locations in memory. So why does my code output both as the same incorrect list?

Output:

```
[[0, [0, 0], 1, [0, 1], 2, [0, 2], 3, [0, 3], 4, [0, 4], 5, [0, 5], 6, [0, 6], 7, [0, 7], 8, [0, 8], 9, [0, 9]], [1, [1, 0], 2, [1, 1], 3, [1, 2], 4, [1, 3], 5, [1, 4], 6, [1, 5], 7, [1, 6], 8, [1, 7], 9, [1, 8], 10, [1, 9]], [2, [2, 0], 3, [2, 1], 4, [2, 2], 5, [2, 3], 6, [2, 4], 7, [2, 5], 8, [2, 6], 9, [2, 7], 10, [2, 8], 11, [2, 9]], [3, [3, 0], 4, [3, 1], 5, [3, 2], 6, [3, 3], 7, [3, 4], 8, [3, 5], 9, [3, 6], 10, [3, 7], 11, [3, 8], 12, [3, 9]], [4, [4, 0], 5, [4, 1], 6, [4, 2], 7, [4, 3], 8, [4, 4], 9, [4, 5], 10, [4, 6], 11, [4, 7], 12, [4, 8], 13, [4, 9]], [5, [5, 0], 6, [5, 1], 7, [5, 2], 8, [5, 3], 9, [5, 4], 10, [5, 5], 11, [5, 6], 12, [5, 7], 13, [5, 8], 14, [5, 9]], [6, [6, 0], 7, [6, 1], 8, [6, 2], 9, [6, 3], 10, [6, 4], 11, [6, 5], 12, [6, 6], 13, [6, 7], 14, [6, 8], 15, [6, 9]], [7, [7, 0], 8, [7, 1], 9, [7, 2], 10, [7, 3], 11, [7, 4], 12, [7, 5], 13, [7, 6], 14, [7, 7], 15, [7, 8], 16, [7, 9]], [8, [8, 0], 9, [8, 1], 10, [8, 2], 11, [8, 3], 12, [8, 4], 13, [8, 5], 14, [8, 6], 15, [8, 7], 16, [8, 8], 17, [8, 9]], [9, [9, 0], 10, [9, 1], 11, [9, 2], 12, [9, 3], 13, [9, 4], 14, [9, 5], 15, [9, 6], 16, [9, 7], 17, [9, 8], 18, [9, 9]]]
```

Comment: You created a shallow copy, which means that all top-level references are shared.  If you don't want that, then create a deep copy.  See `copy.deepcopy` for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Comment: @TomKarzes I see, that would explain it. So what is the point of a shallow copy then if each copy can't be modified individually?

Comment: In many cases you only need a shallow copy, and indeed want a shallow copy.  A deep copy should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: A shallow copy is useful when you know you won't modify any data inside the list. Only the list itself. For example: a list of strings. Strings are immutable objects. If you copy the list to another variable, and append data to a string inside the copy, the original list won't have any modified strings. So, in this case, a shallow copy gets the job done.

Comment: In your example, as you need to modify each row inside the copies of `grid`, a deepcopy is necessary. However, you could assign a secondary shallow copy for each row, right after the first for-loop statement. This way you wouldn't mix `distances` and `coords` data structures anymore.

Comment: Now, why @TomKarzes is saying that `deepcopy` is bad? Simple. Imagine a complex data structure with many and many depth levels. Deepcopy would create a copy for each single object at any depth level of this structure. It would iterate over all of them, which takes a lot of memory for caching data, and time. However, if you just needed a copy only until depth 2 for example, creating your own iteration using shallow copies would be the best choice for more efficiency and less complexity.